# Markdown editor with preview

Tags: textarea, markdown

I'm using [Sundown](https://github.com/vmg/sundown) on my backend to store and render markdown text. Now I would like to edit this text in a browser with some basic formatting. I'd prefer WYSIWYG but can live with a preview panel on a separate element.

But: I fear that editing on mobiles might just be something that one should avoid and fallback to basic text editing. This will be annoying to the non-techie users if we force them to learn Markdown just because they want to "Enter pretty text on my iPhone"... :-/

I've been looking around at some editor components and at the moment I'm testing [CKEditor](http://nightly.ckeditor.com/13-07-05-13-05/standard/samples/uicolor.html). Works fine but seems to be a bit buggy on the iPhone (at least the version I'm testing). Did not find a way to force it to only edit Markdown.. yet.

Another one is [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php). Back in 2010 it seemed [the same story](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=77253#p77253) when it came to mobile devices... just wondering if it's still the case today. It seems to work ok on my device but the layout does not seem optimized for small factor screens... sigh.

Thus:

- I think that a basic editor can work on mobile devices, but I've seen that some sites disable this and gracefully fall back to standard text edits (As StackOverflow does when visting from an iPhone device)
- I just need basic formatting with bold, underline, Header 1 etc and keep the format Markdown - like the SO editor

Any suggestions or comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tinyMCE version 4 actually works just fine on my iPhone, I've put together a small scaled down example for you on their fiddle-site:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Ppdaab

Comment: Interesting... now only if it could post Markdown text ;)

Comment: If you limit the allowed output elements to a bare minimum, like <b>, <i>, <h1> and so on - I think  it would be trivial to "translate" it to markdown server-side. Perhaps it's even possible to allow for direct markdown with tinymce's configuration, but thats a bit tricky.

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend https://stackedit.io/. It converts html (or text) into markdown and doesn't require using Git. You can access it on their website or using the Chrome app. It's lightweight and completely WYSIWYG. Simply type away, it will show you a preview in markdown format. You can then save, publish, share, sync or download the file.